# Will multiple concurrent users of SQL database conflict?

Tags: java, sql-server-2008

I developed a GUI desktop application in Java Netbeans connected to SQL server 2008 database.

This application will be used by multiple users doing update/insert/delete operations **at the same time**. Will this cause a problem?

If it will, how can I overcome that and allow multiple users to use it at the same time?

Comment: Please, take a look at Transactions and Transactions Scopes. What transaction control are you using?

Comment: You can look up `sql server transactions` on your favourite search machine, or use [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174377%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) as a starting point. Put very simply, transactions shield modifications from different sessions (started by different users). GL.

Comment: many thanks for both of you